# Timeleft() function not displaying in frontend (speedrunethereum quest 2)

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I'm kinda new here. Started speedrun ethereum.

I finished the code for quest 2, but timeleft() is not displaying at the front end. It just shows "0" everytime, even redeploying and changing the deadline time.

If i can make this question better, please tell me. Also english is not my first language.

Code snippets:

```
function timeLeft() public view returns(uint256){
        if (block.timestamp >= deadline){
            return 0;
        } else{
            uint timeleft = block.timestamp - deadline;
            return timeleft;
        }
```

```js
<p className="m-0 p-0">{timeLeft ? `${humanizeDuration(Number(timeLeft) * 1000)}` : 0}</p>
```

```js
inputs: [],
          name: "timeLeft",
          outputs: [
            {
              internalType: "uint256",
              name: "",
              type: "uint256",
            },
          ],
          stateMutability: "view",
          type: "function",
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you inverted the sign:

```js
// uint timeleft = block.timestamp - deadline;  wrong
uint timeleft = deadline - block.timestamp;  // correct
```

Comment: Yes, it was that. Thanks for answering my question!